# how do i put utilities.java into a library as a folder so that I can use its methods with multiple java projects?

Tags: java, shared-libraries, unresolved-external, lib, utilities

I have a utilities file named `utilities.java` that is located in my `...\NetbeansProjects\Utilities` folder and I want to use the methods in it in any java project that I work on.

If I right-click `Libraries` folder, there is an option to include `JAR/folder...` so I select that and find and select the `Utilities` folder and Absolute Path to it as shown, which adds the `Utilities` folder to the `Libraries` folder, as shown.

But how do I reference the methods that are in `Utilities.java`?

`import` doesn't offer any help and all I get on every attempted reference is `Cannot find symbol`.

I can't turn `Utilities.java` into a `.jar` file (can I??) because the option to `Compile` is grayed out.

What do I prefix to each such unresolved external reference to successfully link such methods to my code?

Whether I try to just `import` or `import static`, I get error, with suggestions to change to some inappropriate import.

What's irritating is that I think I've successfully done this before....

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshot, it looks like you are using an older version of NetBeans (perhaps v8.2 or similar). I will assume this - but it would be worth upgrading if possible.

Generally, I would recommend creating two NetBeans projects, and then include the utilities project as a dependency in the application project.

You can use the "Library" features of NetBeans (as shown in your screenshot) but I think it is cleaner to just create projects, which ***can then be managed by Git/Mercurial/etc. as needed, as separate projects***, with no need to rely on NetBeans-specific library management features.

**Ant-Based Approach**

For an Ant-based approach (the default for NetBeans 8), that would be something like this:

[image]

The above was created as follows:

Create the utilities project:

1. File > New Project > Java > **Java Class Library**
2. Project Name: MyUtilities
3. Create your package and your Utilities.java file. Add the code you need.
4. Clean and build the project.

Create a project to use the utility JAR:

1. File > New Project > Java > **Java Application**
2. Project Name: MyApplication
3. Right-click on MyApplication in the project explorer and select the Properties pop-up window.
4. Libraries > Add Project - find the MyUtilities project and select it, click on "Add Project JAR Files".

Now you will see that project's jar file listed as one of MyApplication's library dependencies.

After cleaning and building the project you will see a file structure as follows:

[image]

*Note: For NetBeans 12, it's similar, except they now make the choice of an Ant project (vs. Maven, Gradle) explicit, rather than the default.*

**Maven-Based Approach**

It's a similar approach: Two separate projects. In this case they are both "Maven > Java Application" projects - there is no distinction, in contrast to the Ant approach.

The main difference is how you include the utilities JAR in your applications. that depends on how you want to manage your Maven artifacts - and is a bit outside the scope of this question. One way is to follow the [guidelines here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) - but I think there are other approaches, also.